# Absolute value of big complex expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

I am designing a filter and doing calculations in mathematica. I have final form, and I now need to calculate magnitude and phase characteristics of this system. Problem that I have run into is that mathematica doesent seem to want to calculate absolute value. My function is stored in variable `HHH`I ve found solution on this stackexchange via `Simplify@ComplexExpand[Abs@HHH]`
$$
HHH=\frac{s^2+\frac{(\text{C3} \text{R4}
\text{R5} \text{R6b}-\text{C2} (\text{K1}\text{R4} (\text{R5}\text{R6a}+(\text{R5}+\text{R6a})\text{R6b})-(\text{R1}+\text{R4})\text{R5} \text{R6b})) s}{\text{C2}\text{C3} \text{R1} \text{R4} \text{R5}\text{R6b}}+\frac{1}{\text{C2} \text{C3}\text{R1}\text{R4}}}{s^2+\frac{((\text{C2}\text{R1}+\text{C3} \text{R4})(\text{R5}+\text{R6a})\text{R6b}-\text{C2} \text{R4} \text{R5}\text{R6a}) s}{\text{C2} \text{C3}\text{R1} \text{R4}(\text{R5}+\text{R6a})\text{R6b}}+\frac{1}{\text{C2} \text{C3}\text{R1} \text{R4}}}
$$

```
Z1 = R1 + 1/(s*C2); Z2 = (1/R4 + s*C3)^-1; (*K1 = R1b/(R1a+R1b);*)
aaa = Solve[U1*(1/Z1 + 1/Z2) - Uul*K1*(1/Z1) - U3*(1/Z2) == 0 &&
   U2*(1/R6a + 1/R6b + 1/R5) - Uul*(1/R6a) - U3*(1/R6b) == 0 &&
   U1 == U2 &&
   H == U3/Uul, {H, U1, U2, U3}];
Simplify[Collect[Expand[aaa], s, Together]];
solut = FullSimplify[ExpandAll[aaa]][[1]][[1]][[2]];
d = Collect[Denominator [solut], s] // 
   PolynomialForm[#, TraditionalOrder -> True] &;
n = Collect[Numerator [solut], s] // 
   PolynomialForm[#, TraditionalOrder -> True] &;
HH = n/d;
(* Muka oko svođenja na pravi oblik *)
a2 = Coefficient[Denominator [solut], s, 2];
a1 = Coefficient[Denominator [solut], s, 1];
a0 = Coefficient[Denominator [solut], s, 0];
a2nov = FullSimplify[a2/a2];
a1nov = FullSimplify[a1/a2];
a0nov = FullSimplify[a0/a2];
b2 = Coefficient[Numerator [solut], s, 2];
b1 = Coefficient[Numerator [solut], s, 1];
b0 = Coefficient[Numerator [solut], s, 0];
b2nov = FullSimplify[b2/b2];
b1nov = FullSimplify[b1/b2];
b0nov = FullSimplify[b0/b2];
K = Simplify[b2/a2]
HHH = ((s^2*b2nov + s*b1nov + b0nov // 
     PolynomialForm[#, TraditionalOrder -> True] &)/(s^2*a2nov + 
      s*a1nov + a0nov // 
     PolynomialForm[#, TraditionalOrder -> True] &))
s = I*w
ComplexExpand[Abs[HHH], w, TargetFunctions -> {Abs, Arg}]
```

This is my function that i get after a lot of hassle to display exactly like that. Next thing i need to do is introduce substitution $s=iw$ (complex i times omega). Then to calculate magnitude depended on w, I need to calculate `Abs[HHH]` and `Arg[HHH]`. As i mentioned I've had problems with abs and people suggested either the form suggested above or `ComplexExpand@ Abs @HHH`. But both forms return this mess under, and I still have complex i in expression.

$$
\frac{\sqrt{\left(-w^2+\frac{i (\text{C3}\text{R4} \text{R5} \text{R6b}-\text{C2}(\text{K1} \text{R4} (\text{R5}\text{R6a}+(\text{R5}+\text{R6a})\text{R6b})-(\text{R1}+\text{R4})\text{R5} \text{R6b})) w}{\text{C2}\text{C3} \text{R1} \text{R4} \text{R5}\text{R6b}}+\frac{1}{\text{C2} \text{C3}\text{R1}\text{R4}}\right)^2}}{\sqrt{\left(-w^2+\frac{i ((\text{C2} \text{R1}+\text{C3}\text{R4}) (\text{R5}+\text{R6a})\text{R6b}-\text{C2} \text{R4} \text{R5}\text{R6a}) w}{\text{C2} \text{C3}\text{R1} \text{R4}(\text{R5}+\text{R6a})\text{R6b}}+\frac{1}{\text{C2} \text{C3}\text{R1} \text{R4}}\right)^2}}
$$

So how would I tell mathematica to calculate absolute value, and later argument/angle?
P.S. Sory if I forgot any info or messed up formatig, first time posting here.

Comment: Enter your expressions in Mathematica code blocks rather than images. Have you tried the [`TargetFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TargetFunctions.html) option with `ComplexExpand`?

Comment: @BobHanlon I added the code.  The target function doesn't seem to do anything, i always get that solution on the bottom of the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the `FullForm` of your output you will see that you have included the wrapper `PolynomialForm` in the definitions. Such wrappers are intended for display purposes and should be isolated from the definition of the expressions to be displayed, e.g., by using parentheses.

```
Z1 = R1 + 1/(s*C2); 
Z2 = (1/R4 + s*C3)^-1;
(*K1=R1b/(R1a+R1b);*)
aaa = 
 Solve[U1*(1/Z1 + 1/Z2) - Uul*K1*(1/Z1) - U3*(1/Z2) == 0 && 
    U2*(1/R6a + 1/R6b + 1/R5) - Uul*(1/R6a) - U3*(1/R6b) == 0 && 
    U1 == U2 && H == U3/Uul, 
  {H, U1, U2, U3}][[1]];

solut = FullSimplify[aaa][[1, 2]];

d = Collect[Denominator[solut], s];

n = Collect[Numerator[solut], s];

HH = n/d;

(*Muka oko svođenja na pravi oblik*)
{a0, a1, a2} = 
  CoefficientList[Denominator[solut], s];
{a0nov, a1nov, a2nov} = FullSimplify[{a0, a1, a2}/a2];
{b0, b1, b2} = CoefficientList[Numerator[solut], s];
{b0nov, b1nov, b2nov} = FullSimplify[{b0, b1, b2}/b2];
K = Simplify[b2/a2];

HHH = ((s^2*b2nov + s*b1nov + b0nov)/(s^2*a2nov + s*a1nov + a0nov));

s = I*w;

ComplexExpand[Abs[HHH], TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] // Simplify
```

[image]